# Automate shard addition to cluster in mongodb using ansible or shell script

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I'm trying to add shards to existing mongodb cluster. I'm trying to automate this process of adding shards to mongodb cluster from mongos.

Can someone help me in achieving this task.

Comment: What did you try so far? In newest ansible release you have a built-in plugin: [Add or remove shards from a MongoDB Cluster](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mongodb/mongodb_shard_module.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using the built-in plugin to add shards. However, I'm trying to run it on mongos server directly, is that what you're also doing?

Comment: You need to run two steps. Each shard is a replica set, so first you must initiate the replica set (locally on shard mongod). Then you can add the shard to the cluster. I don't know how the ansible plugin works, perhaps you have to initialize it beforehand, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mongodb/mongodb_replicaset_module.html#ansible-collections-community-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-module

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is there any example or tutorial on the [official mongodb shard module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mongodb/mongodb_shard_module.html)  ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the newest ansible release provides a plugin for that. My ansible does not support it yet, so I use this one:

```
---

- hosts: primary
  tasks:

  - name: Set credentials 
    set_fact:
      credentials: "-u admin -p {{ password }} --authenticationDatabase admin"
    check_mode: no
    tags: always

  - name: Check if authentication is enabled
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo {{ credentials }} --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.shard }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: exit
    register: authenticate
    failed_when: false
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: no
    tags: always

  - name: Check if Shard Replicaset is initialized
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo {{ (authenticate.rc == 0) | ternary(credentials, '') }} --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.shard }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: "rs.status().codeName"
    register: rs_status
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: no
    tags: shard

  - name: Init Shard Replicaset
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo {{ (authenticate.rc == 0) | ternary(credentials, '') }} --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.shard }}"
      stdin: |
        var i = rs.initiate()
        if (i.ok != 1) print(i.errmsg)
        var _ = rs.status()
        while (! db.isMaster().ismaster ) sleep(1000)
        const admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
        admin.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "{{ password }}", roles: ["clusterAdmin", "userAdminAnyDatabase"] })
        var _ = admin.auth("admin", "{{ password }}")
        var s = rs.add( { host: "{{ secondary.host }}.{{ domain }}:{{ ports.shard }}" } )
        if (s.ok != 1) print(s.errmsg)
        var a = rs.addArb( "{{ arbiter }}.{{ domain }}:{{ ports.arbiter }}" )
        if (a.ok != 1) print(a.errmsg)
        rs.status().members.map(x => x.name)
        if (i.ok == 1 && s.ok == 1 && a.ok == 1) {print(rs.status().ok)} else {print(0)}
      executable: /bin/bash
    when: rs_status.stdout == 'NotYetInitialized'
    register: ret
    failed_when: (ret.stdout_lines | last | int) != 1
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ret.stdout_lines }}"
    when: not ansible_check_mode and rs_status.stdout != ''
    tags: shard

  - name: Gather current shards 
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo {{ credentials }} --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.router }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: "db.adminCommand({ listShards: 1 }).shards.map(x => x._id)"
    register: exisiting_shards
    run_once: yes
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: no
    delegate_to: "{{ router }}"
    tags: shard

  - name: Add Shards to Cluster
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo {{ credentials }} --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.router }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: |
        var ret = sh.addShard('{{ shard_id }}/{{ inventory_hostname_short }}.{{ domain }}:{{ ports.shard }}')
        if (ret.ok == 1) {printjson({ok: ret.ok, shardAdded: ret.shardAdded})} else {printjson({ok: ret.ok, errmsg: ret.errmsg})}
    when: shard_id not in (exisiting_shards.stdout | from_json)
    register: ret
    failed_when: (ret.stdout | from_json)['ok'] | int != 1
    delegate_to: "{{ router }}"
    tags: shard
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ret.stdout | from_json }} "
    when: not ansible_check_mode and shard_id not in (exisiting_shards.stdout | from_json) and ret.stdout != ''
    delegate_to: "{{ router }}"
    tags: shard


...
```